# Plot font in R and R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm creating a pdf report in R markdown which includes plots generated in R. I'd like the font used for the plot labels, titles, etc. to be different than the default R font. I found a solution that works with R:

```
library(popbio)
A <- matrix(c(0.0, 0.0, 0.24, 0.11, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.71, 0.942), 
           nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
rownames(A) <- c('Juvenile', 'Subadult', 'Adult')
windowsFonts(S = windowsFont('Calibri'))
par(family='S')
stage.vector.plot(pop.projection(A, c(1, 1, 1), 10)$stage.vectors, 
                  main='Stable age distribution')
```

but fails when I try to knit to pdf, generating this error message:

```
Error in replayPlot(x) : invalid font type
Calls: <Anonymous> ... plot2dev -> print -> print.recordedplot -> replayPlot
In addition: There were 45 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
Execution halted
```

I'm honestly not sure if this is a R problem or a R Markdown problem. Is there a better way to change the font using R which will knit fine, or should I handle the font changes using R Markdown alone and, if so, how?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

The warning messages are all repeats of:

```
In replayPlot(x): font family 'S' not found in PostScript font database
```

Comment: Should the font be different to the main font used in your pdf document? If not, try to use the chunk option `dev="tikz"`. The plot will then use the same font as your floating text. If you still want the font in plots to be different to your main font (honestly, why?) you may alter it by using LaTeX code priot to the corresponding chunk.

Comment: @user72959 Could you apply `warnings()` as the error message suggests and add the first warning to your question?

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer I'm trying to get the main text in a serif font and the graphs and plots in sans serif font because I think it looks nicer and is easier to read that way. I set the overall document font just fine in the YAML heading, but the plots still print in R's default font. I've only just started learning R Markdown and haven't dared trying LaTeX yet. What would that LaTeX code look like?